# Stationary Time Series with Limited Data

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting

I have a time series that's stationary with only 42 data points. What I'm trying to do is predict the month. I have several variables, but these variables show little to no correlation with the label I'm trying to predict. Here's how my plot looks when I plot the year-month vs the label:
[image]

I've tried several models: Moving average, weighted moving average, ARIMA, and some neural networks. But I can't seem to find a good fit for this data. How do I go about having the best time series for this type of data in order to have good forecast results?

Comment: How would you define a 'good fit' for this data? I'd say most of the time we are dealing in terms of 'best we got' not a universal benchmark of 'good'. Data looks pretty random unless it is being impacted by other factors but apparently your other variables don't add much value.  Are those spikes increasing in magnitude for a reason or is it random? In addition to what you have done you could try some signal processing filters but a mean forecast may just be 'best' although not necessarily 'good'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have more data for the training? You could use a big amount of past data for training you MA model i.e. and then use this data as your testing dataset in order to spot the month associated if I understood well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).